# Check if IP belongs to Belgium

Tags: php, geolocation

I need to check users IP if it's belongs to Belgium country.

I found a list for i.e: http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/be.html

But how I can compare users IP to these IPs ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Why didn't it work for you? Where are you stuck in specific? What did you research come up with?

Comment: Try MaxMind. They offer IP databases as well as PHP libraries you can use to extract all kinds of geolocation info about IP address. https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-services-and-databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution suggested required some basic programming and database skills. Since you do not mentioned the requirements, I will explain using the widely use PHP and mySQL in the codes.

1. Download and load the the IP2Location LITE DB1 database into mySQL. You can get the table definition from the page https://lite.ip2location.com/database-ip-country
2. Add the following codes in the PHP pages required detection.

> //Configure the MySQL connection $host = 'localhost'; $user = 'root';
>   $password = 'YOUR_PASSWORD'; $database = 'ip2location_database';
>   $table_name = 'ip2location_db1';
>
> //Get the visitor IP address $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
>
> //In case you are testing locally with 127.0.0.1, //you can uncomment
>   the below line to assign the IP address //to 8.8.8.8 (or whatever) for
>   your testing. //$ip = '8.8.8.8';
>
> try{  //Create and perform the SQL query using the PDO    $db = new
>   PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $database . ';charset=utf8',
>   $user, $password);    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,
>   PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
>
> $st = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `' . $table_name . '` WHERE
>   INET_ATON(:ip) <= ip_to LIMIT 1');    $st->execute(array(':ip'=>$ip));
>
> $row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
>
> //Print out the result  var_dump($row); } catch(PDOException $e) {
>     echo $e->getMessage(); }

3. You can review the record output from screen. Use the country_code variable for country result.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use some API to get user/visitor's country as example below.

http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=62.4.159.255

Output

```
{
  "geoplugin_request":"62.4.159.255",
  "geoplugin_status":206,
  "geoplugin_credit":"Some of the returned data includes GeoLite data created by MaxMind, available from <a href=\\'http:\/\/www.maxmind.com\\'>http:\/\/www.maxmind.com<\/a>.",
  "geoplugin_city":"",
  "geoplugin_region":"",
  "geoplugin_areaCode":"0",
  "geoplugin_dmaCode":"0",
  "geoplugin_countryCode":"BE",
  "geoplugin_countryName":"Belgium",
  "geoplugin_continentCode":"EU",
  "geoplugin_latitude":"50.849998",
  "geoplugin_longitude":"4.35",
  "geoplugin_regionCode":"",
  "geoplugin_regionName":null,
  "geoplugin_currencyCode":"EUR",
  "geoplugin_currencySymbol":"&#8364;",
  "geoplugin_currencySymbol_UTF8":"\u20ac",
  "geoplugin_currencyConverter":0.9098
}
```

Code samples are available on [this page](http://www.geoplugin.com/examples).

Answer (score 0):

Use this third party library

Returns json encoded information

`$ip` ip to be verified

```
$location = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/' . $ip));
var_dump($location)
```

Compare country in the $location array